LTspice - Beat frequency
Here is the theory from wikipedia:

Here are my summation of sin on LTspice:



The frequencies are 100 kHz and 120 kHz on the FFT. There is no frequencies at (f1+f2)/2 and no frequencies at (f1-f2)/2.
What is the problem?

Can you show your simulation string and fft setup?

Jess, all you will see are the two spikes with the FFT. It is showing you exactly what it should show. If you want to see your beat frequencies then take your output and run it through a diode and resistor (series connected) and tap off the voltage from the shared resistor/diode node. Then you will see it because the diode will expose the envelope.

Thank you for your help !

@periblepsis If I duplicate Jess' circuit, and use the simulation string ".tran 1m", and standard setup for FFT, i get a peak at 20, 40, 60, 80, 100, 120, 140, 160 etc kHz. EDIT: Yes, FFT on I(R3) of course.

"No problem". It is a theoretical formula, so the simplest is the "good" one.

@MrGerber The 20 has harmonics. Also the diode has moderate distortion. (A Gilbert cell would be a bit better but a lot more complicated to describe in words here.)

@Jess Perhaps it would be better to just read this. It has a nice graphic in it.

@periblepsis I know the 20 has harmonics. But your statement that OPs simulation should only get the two peaks at 100k and 120k in the without a nonlinear element is not correct, you absolutely can get the beat frequency in the fft plot without the diode. Which is what I did.

@MrGerber Please elaborate on exactly how you did that, because that sounds like a simulation error if you did. You need to have a source of nonlinearity to get those sum and difference frequencies.

As i said - replicated OPs circuit, simulation string as above. Plot I(R3), right click on plot, view->fft default setup, mark I(R3) and then I get the peaks as mentioned. To clarify - I'm not arguing whether it should or should not behave like that - just the fact that the simulation setup is relevant for how to get the correct results, and "yes it works" is not really a good answer when OP left out details on how the sim is set up.

@Hearth I've replicated this several times now on different computers, it behaves the same every time. It is connected with the max timestep setting (maybe not suprisingly). When i force the simulation to have max timestep significantly lower than 1/f, the apparent beat frequency goes away, and the 100k and 120k peaks stand out. From max timestep of 100ns and upwards, the modulation frequencies start appearing. I think that is relevant info to give to someone asking a question about FFT in LTspice.


The frequencies are 100 kHz and 120 kHz on the FFT. There is no frequencies at (f1+f2)/2 and no frequencies at (f1-f2)/2.

And there should be none. The wikipedia article doesn't claim that there would be – just that you can represent the two discrete cosines also as product of two others. But a product of cosines doesn't appear in the spectrum as one tone, but as two: exactly the original two tones.
So, the math here is correct, the FFT here is correct, the wikipedia text is correct.  Just your interpretation that there should be new tones in the spectrum is wrong.

The right side of the equation is a product of cosines, not a sum.
If you multiply the right side out, you'll find that your waveform is comprised of two signals: cos(2\$\pi f_1 t\$) and, or plus, cos(2\$\pi f_2 t\$)... the left side of the equation.

Made with microcap v12
The text in the picture shows the "equivalence" of the 2 formulas.

